# Can I use a PL/SQL trigger to check category and concat to a incremental number based on category?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I got a `productID` - P0001KTC and P0001DR.

If product category is kitchen, I will assign a `productID - PROD001KTC`, else if the category is dining room, then the `productID` should be `PROD001DR`.

Is it possible to write a sequence inside a trigger to check the product category and assign an id as mentioned above?

if there is another living room category product inserted then the id will be PROD001LR.

- Kitchen - PROD001KTC，PROD002KTC...
- Dining Room - PROD001DR,PROD002DR....
- Living Room - PROD001LR,PROD002LR...

[image: sample table]

Comment: give at least one example on table.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: It's like i am inserting value into product table, i want the product id auto increment eg P0001KTC,P0002LR. It that possible to do that? It will increase the number 0001,0002,0003, after that concatenate with the category as KTC or LR behind of it.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g

Comment: That is a different question. You did not talk about an incremental number. Please update your question, add the table definition, give some sample inserts, and show the desired outcome.

Comment: Sure, you can write whatever code you like in a trigger. Just look up the 'KTC', 'LR' etc from wherever you store it and concatenate away.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - the tricky bit is getting the next number, not the concatenation

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - Although, re-reading the OP's question, their precise requirement is unclear. I may be about to have wasted the last thirty minutes :(

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. Do you want the numeric element to increment within the Category - `P0001KTC , P0001DR , P0002KTC` - or just monotonically - `P0001KTC , P0002DR , P0003KTC` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

`P0001KTC` is the sort of smart key users love and developers hate. But the customer is king, so here we are.

The customer's requirement is to increment the numeric element within the product category, so that the same number is used for different categories: P0001KTC , P0001DR , P0002KTC, P0001LR, P0002LR, etc. A monotonically increasing sequence cannot do this.

The best implementation is a code control table, that is a table to manage the assigned numbers. Such an approach entails **pessimistic locking**, which serializes access to a Product Category (e.g. KTC). Presumably the users won't be creating new Products very often, so the scaling implications aren't severe.

**Working PoC**

Here's our reference table:

```
create table product_categories (
    product_category_code varchar2(3) not null
    , category_description varchar2(30) not null
    , constraint product_categories_pk primary key (product_category_code)
)
/

create table product_ids (
    product_category_code varchar2(3) not null
    , last_number number(38) default 0 not null
    , constraint product_ids_pk primary key (product_category_code)
    , constraint product_ids_categories_fk foreign key (product_category_code)
                   references product_categories (product_category_code)
) organization index
/
```

May these two tables could be one table, but this implementation offers greater flexibility. Let's create our Product Categories:

```
insert all
    into product_categories (product_category_code, category_description)
        values (cd, descr)
    into product_ids (product_category_code)
        values (cd)
select * from
    ( select 'KTC' as cd, 'Kitchen' as descr from dual union all
      select 'LR' as cd, 'Living Room' as descr from dual union all
      select 'DR' as cd, 'Dining Room' as descr from dual )
/
```

Here's the target table:

```
create table products (
    product_id varchar2(10) not null
    , product_category_code varchar2(3) not null
    , product_description varchar2(30) not null
    , constraint products_pk primary key (product_id)
    , constraint products_fk foreign key (product_category_code)
                   references product_categories (product_category_code)
)
/
```

This function is where the magic happens. The function formats the new Product ID. It does this by taking out a pre-emptive lock on the row for the assigned Category. These locks are retained for the length of the transaction i.e. until the locking session commits or rolls back. So if there are two users creating Kitchen Products one will be left hanging on the other: this is why we generally try to avoid serializing table access in multi-user environments.

```
create or replace function get_product_id
    ( p_category_code in product_categories.product_category_code%type)
    return products.product_id%type
is
    cursor lcur (p_code varchar2)is
        select last_number + 1
        from product_ids
        where product_category_code = p_code
        for update of last_number;
    next_number product_ids.last_number%type;
    return_value products.product_id%type;
begin
    open lcur( p_category_code);
    fetch lcur into next_number;

    if next_number > 999 then
        raise_application_error (-20000
                , 'No more numbers available for ' || p_category_code);
    else
        return_value := 'PROD' || lpad(next_number, 3, '0') || p_category_code;
    end if;

    update product_ids t
    set t.last_number = next_number
    where current of lcur;

    close lcur;

    return return_value;
end get_product_id;
/
```

And here's the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger products_ins_trg
    before insert on products
    for each row
begin
    :new.product_id := get_product_id (:new.product_category_code);
end;
/
```

Obviously, we could put the function code in the trigger body but it's good practice to keep business logic out of triggers.

Lastly, here's some test data...

```
insert into products ( product_category_code, product_description)
values ('KTC', 'Refrigerator')
/
insert into products ( product_category_code, product_description)
values ('DR', 'Dining table')
/
insert into products ( product_category_code, product_description)
values ('KTC', 'Microwave oven')
/
insert into products ( product_category_code, product_description)
values ('DR', 'Dining chair')
/
insert into products ( product_category_code, product_description)
values ('DR', 'Hostess trolley')
/
insert into products ( product_category_code, product_description)
values ('LR', 'Sofa')
/
```

And, lo!

```
SQL> select * from products
  2  /

PRODUCT_ID PRO PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
---------- --- ------------------------------
PROD001KTC KTC Refrigerator
PROD001DR  DR  Dining table
PROD002KTC KTC Microwave oven
PROD002DR  DR  Dining chair
PROD003DR  DR  Hostess trolley
PROD001LR  LR  Sofa

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Note that modelling the smart key as a single column is a bad idea. It is better to build it as a composite key, say `unique (product_category, product_number)`, where `product_number` is generated from the code control table above. We still need  the `product_id`  for display purposes, but it should be derived from the underlying columns. This is easy using virtual columns, like this:

```
create table products (
    product_id varchar2(10) 
       generated always as 'PROD' || to_char(product_no,'FM003') || product_category_code;  
    , product_category_code varchar2(3) not null  
    , product_no number not null
    , product_description varchar2(30) not null
    , constraint products_pk primary key (product_id)
    , constraint products_uk unique (product_category_code, product_no)
    , constraint products_fk foreign key (product_category_code)
                   references product_categories (product_category_code)
)
/
```

Comment: Sorry that my question unclear, i will improve it and thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Sorry to ask, my table look like this but not like yours
CREATE TABLE ProductCategory(
categoryID varchar(15) NOT NULL,
description varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (categoryID)
);  ------ so the way is also same like what you had done?

Comment: Yes, the differences are trivial

Comment: Ok, but i only have 2 tables, which are product and productCategory. How do i get the number for productID just like what you done? Appreciate if you could guide me.

Comment: You have two choices: add the third table, as I have done, or add a `last_number` to the `productCategory` table.

Comment: there is no other choices already besides add 3rd table or last_number to productCategory table?

Comment: Well the number has to come from somewhere. If you don't like those  alternatives you're left with running `MAX()` over a query which extracts the numeric element from the Product ID filtered by Product Category. Which is the worst possible, least scalable implementation; and you still need to pre-emptively lock the table in a multi-user application.

Comment: Okay, noted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The image shows a different format for *productid* than what you write in the question. I will assume you want the "PROD" prefix as in the image, and that you can deal with changing those characters in the solution below, if needed.

Also, you write twice the same number (001) in the question, yet in the image, and in the comments you provided, you indicate the numbering should increment always. So this solution will have an always incrementing number.

## Proposed Solution

You should store the incremental number separately, and have that as the real *id*.
The formatted *productID* could then be a derived column. Since Oracle 11g R1 you can create [virtual columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) in a table, so you don't really need a trigger for that:

Here is an example script, which creates the table and the sequence:

```
create table products (
    id number not null,
    category varchar2(100),
    productid as (
           'PROD'||
           to_char(id, 'FM000') ||
           case category when 'Kitchen' then 'KTC'
                         when 'LivingRoom' then 'LR'
                         else '???'
           end ) virtual,
    constraint pk_product_id primary key (id),
);

-- create sequence for inserting incremental id value
create sequence product_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
```

You insert data like this, without specifying values for the virtual *productid* column:

```
-- Insert data
insert into products (id, category) values (product_seq.nextval, 'Kitchen');
insert into products (id, category) values (product_seq.nextval, 'LivingRoom');
```

And when you select data from the table:

```
select * from products
```

You get:

```
ID | CATEGORY   | PRODUCTID
---+------------+-----------
 1 | Kitchen    | PROD001KTC
 2 | LivingRoom | PROD002LR
```

Note that you'll get into trouble if your *id* surpasses 999, as then the 3-digit format will not work any more. Oracle will then generate `###` for the `to_char` result, so you'll run into duplicate *productid* values soon.

If you have many more categories than those two (Kitchen & LivingRoom), then you should not extend the earlier mentioned `case` statement with those values. Instead you should create a reference table for it (let's call it *categories*), with values like this:

```
Code | Name
-----+---------------
KTC  | Kitchen
LR   | Living Room
 ... | ...
```

Once you have that table, where *Code* should be unique, you can just store the code in the *products* table, not the description:

```
create table products (
    id number not null,
    category_code varchar2(10),
    productid as (
           'PROD'||
           to_char(id, 'FM000') ||
           category_code) virtual,
    constraint pk_product_id primary key (id),
    constraint fk_product_category foreign key (category_code)
               references catgories(code)
);
```

You would insert values like this:

```
insert into products (id, category_code) values (product_seq.nextval, 'KTC');
insert into products (id, category_code) values (product_seq.nextval, 'LR');
```

And when you want to select data from the table with the category names included:

```
select     product.productid, categories.name
from       products
inner join categories on product.category_code = categories.code
```

Comment: This won't produce the IDs specified in the opening line: `P0001KTC` and `P0001DR`. Although I agree the OP's requirement is unclear.

Comment: The OP's picture of desired outcome is different from what he writes, but I don't think the difference between "PROD" and "P" is essential to the question or solution...

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the repeated numeric element: it's `001` in both cases. So is that the requirement or a typo?

Comment: Indeed unclear, but the OP comments to his own question: *...i want the product id auto increment eg P0001KTC,P0002LR. It that possible to do that? It will increase the number 0001,0002,0003, after that concatenate with the category as KTC or LR behind of it.*. This seems to imply he really has a typo in his question, and the numbering should be as in the image he provided.

Comment: Sorry that my question unclear, i will improve it and thanks for feedback!