# Variable pre-suffix and auto incremented post suffix for 12 digit non primary key, jpa Generator

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I would like to mention the problem statement first. I have a Vehicle class and table in oracle DB. Vehicle class has a primary key id and non primary key as Vehicle-ID. Vehicle can be of only pre-defined 16 types, car scooter, truck etc

Vehicle-ID is 12 digit long. Starting two digits of a vehicle is in between 01,02 to 16(Thats DB value of VehicleType Enum of all possible 16 vehicles). And last 10 digits needs to be in between 0000000001 to 9999999999.

Now if I insert first vehicle as car and car has DB value 01 from VehicleEnum class then the id of this car should be 010000000001 and later if I like to insert truck then its vehicle-id should be 020000000001.

One possibility is to create 16 auto-incremented sequence in oracle and add pre-suffix from JPA generator, which extends IdentifierGenerator. Can there be  another solution to  solve this problem, without creating 16 sequences.

Comment: The only option to 16 sequences is to build a code control table, and maintain the count for each category yourself. Please read [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682205/146325).

Comment: Its a database solution. I was looking for some JPA related solution, if there is any JPA customized generator to fulfill this aim.

Comment: You need to persist the last assigned number for each class somewhere. So, if not in the database then where?